# Error check in book - Jensen inequality and binomial coefficient

Tags: proof-verification, binomial-coefficients, jensen-inequality

I'm reading "Ramsey Theory" by Graham, Rothschild and Spencer, 2nd edition ([see here](https://books.google.es/books?id=55oXT60dC54C&pg=PA133&lpg=PA133&dq=ramsey+theory&source=bl&ots=LqG7XGMJtr&sig=ACfU3U0tlaPl3HGZucky8HF86IBP4Yd4tQ&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjT29b02_LgAhUImRoKHfkLA-EQ6AEwAnoECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=ramsey%20theory&f=false)). Page 111 & 112, they state

1. For a given $a$, the function $f:x\mapsto \binom{x}{a}$ is concave
2. For a given concave function, with $\bar{x}=(x_1+\ldots+x_n)/n$
   $$ \sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i) \geq nf(\bar{x})$$
3. So that we have 
   $$\sum_i \binom{x_i}{a} \geq n \binom{\frac{1}{n}\sum_i x_i}{a}$$

The second point is, without stating it, Jensen inequality. But if I'm not mistaken, Points 1 and 2 are backward. The binomial function is convex, and the Jensen inequality is stated at reverse (this is the statement for convex functions).

In the end, these two mistakes cancel, giving a good results.

Could anyone confirm?